# Azure Mobile Apps, Authorization works, but token expiration doesn't work

Tags: c#, azure, jwt, azure-mobile-services

I am using custom authentication and generating a JWT token.

When I post to any service, any authorization attribute say `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` is respected and users who don't have this role are getting an authorisation error (good!). This highlights to me that the token generation and posting back works!

However, when a token expires, nothing happens. And it is treated as a valid token while I should be getting some sort of exception, my code is this:

```
app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions()
{
    SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authSigningKey"],
    ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authAudience"] },
    ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["authIssuer"] },
    TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
});
```

And:

```
JwtSecurityToken token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(
new Claim[] { new 
Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, assertion["username"]) },
                mySigningKey,
                myAppURL,
                myAppURL,
                // Setting very short time to test expiration
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

**I am testing locally and I am expecting an error being sent to the client stating an expired token. What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 5-minute expiration grace period to account for clock-skew. I'm guessing that you're sending this token sometime after the 10 seconds but before the 5 minute grace period expires. Try waiting for longer than 5 minutes to confirm whether the token has expired.

Comment: After wasted hours of investigation, this was the solution. Azure team should have added an exception or some sort of alert for less than 5 minutes. Good spot.

Comment: I know they recommend to consider a clock skew of 15 mins even, but the number is ridiculous. Also, their servers (at least according to various posts here on S/O) are pretty much in sync with time skew in the range of < 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

When a token expires, nothing happens directly.  When you first try to use that token, you should get a 401 Unauthorized error for any endpoint using the `[Authorize]` attribute.  That's because the token you are submitting is no longer valid.